# Link JIRA cloud and Bitbucket cloud

Tags: bitbucket, jira

I've been trying to connect Bitbucket cloud and JIRA cloud altogether for a while unsuccessfully.
When I enter JIRA URL in Bitbucket I get the following error message :
[image]

And when I try the other way around, connect to Bitbucket from JIRA I get this error message :
[image]

Please ask if you need further info about my setup.

**Edit : After following @grizzthedj answer :**

- I create the OATH 2.0 key on Bitbucket
- I connected to JIRA and get the following message : 
  [image]
- I'm like "nevermind invalid credentials, I'm connected on my bitbucket account" (And I don't see any "retry log in options anyway")
- After clicking "Link to Bitbucket account" I end up having the "Mmmm... That didn't work" message from above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be missing steps that you may have already done, but you need to create an OAuth access token for your Bitbucket Cloud account, then you need to add this token to your JIRA project. You will need admin level access on both systems in order for the DVCS connector to be able to integrate them.

Exact steps and more details can be found here.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/connect-bitbucket-cloud-to-jira-server-applications-814208991.html

Comment: If you followed the steps in the atlassian docs, it will work(I have done the integration myself). Perhaps try the following, if you haven't tried already. Make sure you are logged in both BitBucket and JIRA, before you try the integration. I did this, and I wasn't prompted for credentials at all. Also double check that the user you are logged in as, is in the admin group(in both systems). Also try resetting passwords to ensure they are correct? Hard to troubleshoot not seeing things real time.

Comment: I had pretty much everything you said done. I tried resetting password but it didn't work. Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Just for the record I mark your answer as accepted because I guess the problem is too specific and not detailed enough. You provided the ressource so I guess that's a fair answer.

Comment: Perhaps you can reach out to Atlassian directly to help you with this integration. They may have experienced this issue with other customers.

Comment: Sadly I did. No answer from them :/

Comment: That's not really helpful, and quite surprising actually. -1 for atlassian.